# Bypassing cloudfare detection in a loop using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, undetected-chromedriver

I am trying to scraping yell.com using selenium undetected browser package and it is bypassing the first detection on initial page fine but when I try to loop over pages and somehow one of those pages gets redirected to cloudfare it is not bypassing that detection. For example: for first page it works perfectly and now comes to the second page scrape few listings and suddenly one of the listing links get redirected and uc browser doesn't bypass the detection like it did on initial page. Here is my code:

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time
from selectolax.parser import HTMLParser
import pandas as pd


options = uc.ChromeOptions()
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options, headless=False, use_subprocess=True)
driver.execute_script("window.open('https://www.yell.com/l/solicitors.html', '_blank')")
time.sleep(15)
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div/div/div/div/ul[1]"))
)

html = HTMLParser(driver.page_source)
link = html.css_first("div.findLinks--item a").attributes["href"]
page_url = "https://www.yell.com" + link
driver.get(page_url)
page_html = HTMLParser(driver.page_source)

company_data = []


last_page_str = page_html.css("div.col-sm-14.col-md-16.col-lg-14.text-center a")[
    -1
].attributes["aria-label"]
last_page_no = int(last_page_str.split(" ")[-1])


for page in range(1, last_page_no + 1):
    paginated_url = f"https://www.yell.com/ucs/UcsSearchAction.do?find=Y&keywords=solicitors&location=aberdeen&pageNum={page}"
    print(f"Scraping {paginated_url}...")
    driver.get(paginated_url)
    listing_page = HTMLParser(driver.page_source)
    listings = [
        li.attributes["content"] for li in listing_page.css('meta[itemprop="url"]')
    ]
    aberdeen_listings = [al for al in listings if "aberdeen" in al]
    clean_listings = list(dict.fromkeys(aberdeen_listings))
    for listing in clean_listings:
        driver.get(listing)
        listing_html = HTMLParser(driver.page_source)
        if driver.title == "Just a moment...":
            driver.execute_script("window.open('" + listing + "', '_blank')")
            print("executed_script")
            time.sleep(15)
            driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
            print("window_handles")
            WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located(
                    (
                        By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                        "h1.text-h1.businessCard--businessName",
                    )
                )
            )
            listing_html = HTMLParser(driver.page_source)
        name = listing_html.css_first("h1.text-h1.businessCard--businessName").text()
        try:
            street_address = listing_html.css_first(
                'span[itemprop="streetAddress"]'
            ).text()
            locality = listing_html.css_first('span[itemprop="addressLocality"]').text()
            postal_code = listing_html.css_first('span[itemprop="postalCode"]').text()
            address = street_address + "," + locality + "," + postal_code
        except AttributeError:
            address = "N/A"
        try:
            website = listing_html.css_first('a[itemprop="url"]').attributes["href"]
        except AttributeError:
            website = "N/A"
        phone = listing_html.css_first("span.business--telephoneNumber").text()
        company_data.append(
            {
                "Company_Name": name,
                "Address": address,
                "Website": website,
                "Phone": phone,
            }
        )
        time.sleep(5)

print(company_data)
df = pd.DataFrame(company_data)
clean_df = df.drop_duplicates(keep="first")
clean_df.to_csv("yell_solicitors_listings.csv", index=False)
```

scraper crashed on this web driver wait:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
                EC.presence_of_element_located(
                    (
                        By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                        "h1.text-h1.businessCard--businessName",
                    )
                )
            )
```

I'd like to know is there any issue with my code here? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks